# How to update multiple fields in nested array object by $set operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to perform simple update operation to nested subdocument (task) in user inboxTasks array. When I update single field (eg. name), everything work fine, name is updated and promise return Task. But when I try to use spread operator to update multiple fields, update work, but subdocument get new `_id`.

```js
export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: String,
  inboxTasks: [InboxTaskSchema]
});
```

```js
export const InboxTaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  priority: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});
```

```js
export class UpdateInboxTaskDto {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly priority: boolean;
}
```

This code works, update single name property of task subdocument.

```js
async updateInboxTask(userId: string, taskId: string, taskUpdate: UpdateInboxTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
    this.logger.debug(taskUpdate);
    await this.userModel
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          _id: userId,
          'inboxTasks._id': taskId
        },
        {
          $set: {
            inboxTasks.$.name': taskUpdate.name // WORK FOR SINGLE FIELD
            //  'inboxTasks.$': { ...taskUpdate }  // DON'T WORK AS EXPECTED
          }
        },
        {}
      )
      .exec();

    const user = await this.userModel.findById(userId);
    return user.inboxTasks.find(task => task.id === taskId);
  }
```

It returns:

```
Mongoose: users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId("5dbca9b2a3e97610c8366d76"), 'inboxTasks._id': ObjectId("5dbd52be1f8d743e6496aaef") }, { '$set': { 'inboxTasks.$.name': 'Changed task name' } }, { upsert: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: true })
```

But I want to update every field that appear in `taskUpdate: UpdateInboxTaskDto`. When I change to commented code, it create new `_id` for task.

Returns:

```
Mongoose: users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId("5dbca9b2a3e97610c8366d76"), 'inboxTasks._id': ObjectId("5dbd52be1f8d743e6496aaef") }, { '$set': { 'inboxTasks.$': { completed: false, priority: true, _id: ObjectId("5dbd5bf73f00d112e48d79c0"), name: 'Changed task name' } } }, { upsert: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: true })`
```

Comment: No the spread here of `{ ...taskUpdate }` does little more than just `taskUpdate` and thus you are just "replacing" the entire matched array index with that object. You actually need to specify each property distinctly within a `$set`, OR construct those distinct statements just as the linked answer demonstrates.